# How to change function name in the Hyperledger - Using CouchDB tutorial?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have go through the Using CouchDB tutorial without problems. Now when I try to change the name of the functions I get an error message, but when I run the invocations with the old names they still works. How can I update the names properly?

I have followed the tutorial [Using CouchDB](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html) without any troubles. Now I want to customize the code for my purpose. I have deleted the remaining functions I don't want to use and have now initMarble and queryMarbles as the only two invoke functions. If I keep it like this, it works, but if I change the function names to something else like initPharma and queryPharma and I ran the initPharma as an argument, I get the following error message:

> Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500
>   message:"Received unknown function invocation"

It seems like I don't get my script uploaded correct to the container.
When I do changes I use the follow commands:

```
./byfn.sh down

./byfn.sh up -c mychannel -s couchdb

docker exec -it cli bash

peer chaincode install -n pharma -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/pharma03

export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n pharma -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR ('Org0MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer')"
```

The updated code looks like this:

```
func main() {
    err := shim.Start(new(SimpleChaincode))
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error starting Simple chaincode: %s", err)
    }
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
fmt.Println("invoke is running " + function)

if function == "initPharma" { //create a new marble
    return t.initPharma(stub, args)
} else if function == "queryPharma" { //find marbles based on an ad hoc rich query
    return t.queryPharma(stub, args)
}

fmt.Println("invoke did not find func: " + function) //error
return shim.Error("Received unknown function invocation")
}
```

How can I update my function names and not get stuck with the original names from the tutorial?

Comment: Fo Go chaincodes I think you have to have 2 functions `Init` and `Invoke` - so if you have removed Init you will need to replace it.  This is also true for JavaScript unless you use the New High-Level programming model.

Comment: @RThatcher Thanks for your comment. I have added more code, so you can see the Init and Invoke functions. It is only initMarble and queryMarbles which have been changed to initPharma and queryPharma which causes the error.

Comment: Your code is correct. It should work. I think, there is some other issue, like while installing the chaincode you are installing old chaincode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This answer was provided by the OP, as an edit to the question, and moved here to conform to site guidelines.

---

Solved by updating the index through a new index and deleting the old one in Fauxton UI. So there are no errors in the code as commented by Ankit Kamra.